# Is there a tool that displays the build depenency graph and target sequence from an MS Build project file?

Tags: build, msbuild

Is there a tool that can, given an MS Build project file, build a visual that shows which target will be executed when and from which imported file?

If given a solution file, it builds a visual of the sequence in which the projects will be built?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can create a binary log using the `-bl` argument to msbuild:

```
msbuild -bl the.sln
```

Wich will create an `msbuild.binlog` file which you can open using the [MSBuild Structured LogViewer](http://msbuildlog.com) which will display the dependency graph of the targets.

Comment: Thank you. That's just what I wanted.

Comment: msbuild version 14.0.25420.1 gives error: `MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch. Switch: -bl`

Comment: @Heri use a newer msbuild version from the visual studio developer command prompt, not the version in C:\Windows\..

Comment: Is there any equivalent tool that works on Mac?